# Expressing the coordinate dependent and indepent forms of the $(0,1)$ tensor in different coordinate systems

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms, tensors, general-relativity, index-notation

I'm studying general relativity and and learning up on tensors through a lecture series. It says that $\omega_\mu$ represents a 1-form in the $x^\mu$ coordinate system. The coordinate independent 1-form is denoted by $\omega$ as $\omega = \omega_\mu \mathrm{d}x^\mu$. However, if I assume the definition of the 1-form when using two different coordinate systems $x^\mu$ and $x^{\mu'}$, the following is true

$$\omega_{\mu'} = \frac{\partial x^\mu}{\partial x^{\mu'}} \omega_\mu$$

then I can prove the following:

$$\omega_{\mu'} \mathrm{d}x^{\mu'} = \omega_\mu \mathrm{d}x^\mu$$

However, this is how a scalar transforms. So, is $\omega = \omega_\mu \mathrm{d}x^\mu$ a scalar?

Answer (score 1):

The equation $$\omega_{\mu'} \mathrm{d}x^{\mu'} = \omega_\mu \mathrm{d}x^\mu$$ does not say it transforms like a scalar; instead it says that both expressions $\omega_{\mu'} \mathrm{d}x^{\mu'}, \omega_\mu \mathrm{d}x^\mu$ are representing the same object $\omega$. The object $\omega=\omega_\mu dx^\mu$ is a differential $1$-form, not a scalar field.

Comment: The lectures I am listening to, say that a defining feature of a scalar $f$ is that it transforms under a change of coordinates ($x^{\mu'} \rightarrow x^\mu$) as $f(x^{\mu'}) = f(x^\mu(x^{\mu'}))$. For example, for a vector $v \equiv v^\mu \frac{\partial }{\partial x^\mu}$ and a scalar $f$, the quantity $vf \equiv v^\mu \frac{\partial f}{\partial x^\mu}$ can be shown to be a scalar because the following holds true: $v^{\mu'} \frac{\partial f(x^{\mu'})}{\partial x^{\mu'}} = v^\mu \frac{\partial f(x^\mu)}{\partial x^\mu}$. If this is incorrect, can you tell me how to test for a scalar.